Alternative definitions outer semidirect product
I am working with outer semidirect products and have come across two definitions that are slightly different.
Let $N,H$ be two groups and $\theta: H \to \text{Aut}(N)$ a group morphism. Then in both definitions the set of elements in the semidirect product $N \rtimes_\theta H$ is the same as the Cartesion product $N\times H$. However, I have seen the following two definitions for the group operation.

For all $x,y \in N$ and $s,t \in H$, $$ (x,t) \cdot (y,s) = (x \cdot \theta(t)(y), ts).$$
For all $x,y \in N$ and $s,t \in H$, $$ (x,t) \cdot (y,s) = (\theta(s)(x)\cdot y, ts).$$

I think the first one is more common, but I saw the second definition in some places too.
My question is: How do these definitions relate to each other? I tried to show that the two versions of the semidirect product that we defined above are isomorphic, but without succes.
Does another relation hold? For example, is $N \rtimes_\theta H$ with the first definition isomorphic to $N \rtimes_\varphi H$ with the second definition where $\varphi$ is another morphism $H \to \text{Aut}(N)$?
I suspect that they are in some way related, because a lot of properties can be proven for both definitions in a really similar way. For example, for both definitions, it is easy to prove that the semidirect product of two torsion-free groups is again torsion-free.
Thanks in advance!

I suppose you could try seeing whether $$x\cdot \theta(t)(y)=\theta(s)(x)\cdot y.$$ It looks like a commutative diagram might help.

Could you cite your sources, please?

I suspect that the first one is regarding ${\rm Aut}(N)$ as acting on $N$ on the left, and the second one on the right.

I have moved this away from the general (i.e., [tag:abstract-algebra]) towards the technical (i.e., [tag:automorphism-group] and [tag:group-actions]), plus the [tag:definition] tag.

I think we can conclude from the answers so far that the question is poorly defined (no pun intended): definition 2 is wrong.

Again: please cite your sources, because I can't find your definition 2 anywhere, assuming it's accurate.

@Shaun You can take a look at the nLab page on semidirect products. They do not give the formula, but make a comment about "right" semidirect products. If you want to see them "in action", you can look for the paper Regularity and completeness of half-Lie groups by Bauer, Harms and Michor.  Most references do not introduce them because, as I showed in my answer, you can always obtain a "left" semidirect product by composing with the inversion map, so there is really no need for them, I think.

As Derek Holt said in the comments, for the second definition to provide a group law we need that $\theta$ is a antihomomorphism. Try to check associativity and you will realize why.
Let $\iota:H\to H$ the inversion map $h\mapsto h^{-1}$. Then if $\theta:H\to \mathrm{Aut}(N)$ is a group homomorphism, then $\varphi=\theta\circ \iota$ is a group antihomomorphism. Denote by $N\rtimes_\theta H$ the group obtained from the first definition, and $N\rtimes^\varphi H$ the group obtained by the second definition for the antihomomorphism $\varphi$. The map
$$
f:N\rtimes_\theta H\to N\rtimes^\varphi H
$$
given by
$$
f(x,t) = (\theta(t^{-1})(x),t)
$$
is a group isomorphism, as you can easily verify. Thus, under the consideration given in the first paragraph, both groups are indeed isomorphic.
